# Need to build a GUI using hibernate and spring where we can update/alter schema structures from user interface

Tags: spring, hibernate

Please guide me on this how to update entity classes when schema is updated and how to make sure the entity classes and table schema are in sink.
Scenario: User can add a new column by clicking add column button from screen.
How do i update schema using hibernate?

Comment: You use JPA/Hibernate on a fixed schema. If one would like to modify the schema at runtime, one needs to construct a program which would restart certain processes while continuing to present a functional GUI to the user. It seems possible to do, however this is not a "clean" design, meaning that you would need to configure the various processes yourself with regards to their memory needs, for example (suggestion: Spring MVC backend which exposes RESTful services, whose source code is modified by your GUI upon change in schema - use e.g. ANTLR, and which is restarted every time schema changes).

Comment: ..but the question you need to ask yourself is of course: do you **really** need that (modifying schema)?

Comment: purpose of module is to update schema structure, so how can i alter tables and at the same time how can i read schema's. Should we use ANTLR with hibernate or jus spring rest and antlr ?

Comment: I skipped some steps; the point is that your program, on each desired schema change, will need: 1. stop backend (stop the server where the Spring RESTful webapp, which functions as RESTful backend, is deployed). 2. issue DDL commands to your db (to update schema). 3. update entity classes sources of the (Spring/JPA) backend; this can be done "manually" or in a "cleaner way" using ANTLR/StringTemplate etc. 4. build backend webapp. 5. deploy backend to server and start server. During all this cycle your GUI should be aware that the backend is down.

Comment: That it is  in principle possible to do is one thing; but I myself would really try to avoid doing all this, since it will take time, and will most probably involve writing code which would turn out to be not very much maintainable/portable to another environment. Instead I would try to think hard about how to get the work which you need to get done, done without modifying schema (another layer of abstraction, perhaps? just guessing here),